# How to fix #links to anchors when the don't work in Google but do in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

this is a quick question.

My personal site for my business; www.webparity.net all of a sudden stopped working in Chrome. Meaning, the links to the anchors on the page in the FRONT.JS code doesn't work anymore but it works fine in Safari and Firefox. I'm dumbfounded.

Here's the linking code in the menu system.

```
<div id="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#text">Capabilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the JS code in FRONT.JS at line 111.

```
/* animated scrolling */

$('.scroll-to, #navigation a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var full_url = this.href;
    var parts = full_url.split("#");
    var trgt = parts[1];

    $('body').scrollTo($('#' + trgt), 800, {offset: -50});

});
```

When I step through, there are no errors, just the that the menu will not work. BUT, that being said, however, the SCROLL TO TOP does in-fact, work!

This has been working for over a year when I built it.

I commented out the GTM at the bottom of the INDEX FILE.  But there are GOOGLE errors all over the place. One thing I tried, was a SECURITY STRIPPED version of CHROME and it STILL DOESN'T WORK!

This is driving me nuts trying to find what the problem is. I need to get this fixed as this is my bread and butter!

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your developer console?

Comment: console.log the jquery part to make sure it is what it should be.Also after a bit of googling I see chrome bug issues relating to internal links.

Comment: Mihai, ah, this is bizarre. So it's a potential CHROME BUG and why Firefox works (THANK GOD). Even Internet Exploder (EDGE) works.  So, is there a workaround for this bug?  David R. there are no bugs in the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in chrome, window is scrolling not body.

and it's better to use .scrollTop() instead of scrollTo. jQuery has no scrollTo method

use this :

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#' + trgt), 800, {offset: -50});
$('body').scrollTop($('#' + trgt), 800, {offset: -50});
```

Comment: Emad, so what you're saying is use ScrollTop even though I want to "SCROLL" downwards for the sections of my site?

Comment: @Peter find your target offset().top length and put it in scrollTop().

Comment: So, Emad, this doesn't work, pal. See the code... the $('window') simply has every menu SCROLL TO THE TOP and NOT DOWN and $('body') does NOTHING. Any other suggestions?